# How to change an ASP.net MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a simple way of generating a new Route-URL without all this faff.

I'm currently Handling several routes to the same view, all of which end with 
/{pagenumber}

All I'm trying to do is delete everything back to the last backslash and replace the number.

I was trying to avoid using the URL Maker as it seems a tad overkill for pagination but all suggestions welcome…

Heres the method im using for pagination

```
#region Create View Pagination
/// <summary>
/// Create Pagination For Display
/// </summary>
/// <param name="TotalPgs"></param>
/// <param name="currentPg"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string pagnationStr(int TotalPgs, int currentPg)
{
    string tmp = "";
    string URLX = "";

    URLX = string.Format("{0}", base.Request.Url);

    int pageSet = 10;

    //Previous Link
    if (currentPg > 1) tmp += "<li><a href='" + URLX + (currentPg - 1) + "'>Previous</a></li>";

    //Standard Pagination
    tmp += "<ul class=\"pagination\">";
    for (int i = currentPg; i < TotalPgs; i++)
    {
        tmp += "<li><a href='" + URLX + i + "'>" + i.ToString() + "</a></li>";
        if (pageSet < 1) break;
        pageSet--;
    }
    tmp += "</ul>";

    return tmp;
}
#endregion
```

- various bits of this normally come from the app-settings I've replaced them with numbers to be complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing works two ways - it will take in a request url and match the correct resource, or you can ask routing to generate you an URL based on the parameters you have.

```
RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(
                                context, 
                                new RouteValueDictionary(
                                       {param1name, param1value},
                                       {param2name, param2value}...
                                 )
                               );
```

This will generate you a URL to the resource you'd like, based on your parameter values.
If you pass in "controller" = "whatever", "action" = "whatever", and "pagenumber" = currentpg, you should get the URL that you want, without having to manually parse the URLs. This is also more scalable should your routes change in the future.

Any extra parameters you pass into GetVirtualPath that are not consumed by the route matching will be appended as querystring parameters.